# use yylex() twice in a row

Tags: c, parsing, lex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

So my question is pretty simple, I guess it has been answered before but I can't get my hands on a good thread about it: can I parse a file once, gather some needed information to initialize my structures and then parse it "for real" a second time?

When I call `yylex()` twice it just doesn't seem to do anything. Or is it that I need to reset the read pointer of my file? I'm a C noob so it may be a stupid question! Anyway any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does your `.l` file look like?

Comment: well I resolved this problem two days ago so I just posted the solution I adopted !

Comment: nah you're not dumb, I re-edited flags before answering that's why you didn't see the answer before commenting :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yyrestart(FILE *in)`.

But note that the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/How-can-I-build-a-two_002dpass-scanner_003f.html) suggests that instead of a two-pass scanner like this, you should build a parse tree the first time.

Comment: I'll give you the answer for the yyrestart function. Though I'm a bit sad everybody answer after 1 week of nothing and after I answer my own question x)

Comment: Most likely no one answered when you posted because it was 11pm on a Tuesday (EST).  [Midday is generally better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions)

Answer (score 1):

So here it is if it interests someone :

I tried to use `rewind`, a function available through `#include <stdio.h>`. Though, after having written something like :

```
yylex();
rewind(yyin);
yylex();
```

I still had a bad behavior as a result. Here is how I totally solved my problem :
In my lexer, I added :

```
<<EOF>>    yyterminate();
```

After this modification and the code detailed above, the resulting code ran as expected.

I hope that will be of some use !

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you've hit the end of the file. You need to reinitialize your read pointer. However, check out [this link](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/How-can-I-build-a-two_002dpass-scanner_003f.html) for what would probably be a better solution.

Comment: well, in my case I didn't even use a grammar, so a parse tree was totally overkill. I actually needed two passes to be able to know in advance the size of the data structures that were going to welcome the data, because managing dynamic resizing and so on is a pain for a C noob like me ! Thanks for your answer anyway, appreciated :)